# Getting NaN Values after Splitting with Boolean Masking

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I am trying to split a huge dataframe into smaller dataframes based on values on a specific column.

What I basically did was I created a for loop then assigned each dataframe to a dictionary.

However when I call the items from the dictionary all values are NaN except for the cell_id values that I used for splitting.

Why would this happen?

Also I would appreciate if there are more practical ways to do this.

```
df_sliced_dict = {}

for cell in ex_df['cell_id'].unique():

   df_sliced_dict[cell] = ex_df[ex_df.loc[:, ['cell_id']] == cell]
```

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe along with the desired output; then it's easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
df_sliced_dict[cell] = ex_df[ex_df.loc[:, ['cell_id']] == cell]
```

with

```
df_sliced_dict[cell] = ex_df[ex_df['cell_id'] == cell]
```

inside the for-loop and it will work as expected.

The problem is that `ex_df.loc[:, ['cell_id']]` (or `ex_df[['cell_id']]`) is a DataFrame, not a Series, and you want a Series to construct your boolean mask.